# Oracle compare number date between two dates

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a field with the data type of number which represents a date
eg: 20060421

I have two other fields in other table with the data type of Date.

I want to retrieve the rows from the first table that lies between those  two Dates present in the other table.

How Can I compare the date in simple number format in a between clause of two Dates of data type Date.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution for you here is to just cast the numeric date into a date type and then just use the built-in `BETWEEN` function.

```
-- sample cast
select to_date(to_char(20060801),'YYYYMMDD') from dual
```

so your solution should look something like this:

```
select *
from numericDatesTable t1, otherTable t2
where to_date(to_char(t1.date),'YYYYMMDD') between t2.date1 and t2.date2
```